# Arraylist of type superclass to hold various subclass types

Tags: java, object, arraylist

The functions in my classes have worked after being tested. The ColorDrop creates a falling drop of specified color. The SpeedDrop of specified speed and so forth.
I want to put my drops in a list an mass produce them in the GUI.
Drop is the superclass, ColorDrop and SpeedDrop are subclasses that extend the superclass.
The code compile, but the GUI is blank. Am i assembling my arraylist wrong? Or am I calling methods on objects of that list incorrectly?

```
   package advancedobject;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyGooDrop extends Goo {

    Drop testDrop;
    Drop colorDrop;
    Drop fastDrop;
    Drop wavyDrop;
    int random = (int) Math.random()*width; 
    ArrayList<Drop> drops;
    public MyGooDrop() 
    {

        testDrop = new Drop(width/2, -10, 10);
        colorDrop =  new ColorDrop(width/3, -10, 10, Color.BLUE);
        fastDrop = new SpeedDrop ( (width * 3/4), -10, 10, 5);
        wavyDrop = new WavyDrop (-10, height/2, 10);
        drops = new ArrayList<Drop>();
        fillDropList();
    }

      public void fillDropList ()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<= 12; i++)
        {
           if (i <= 4)
           drops.add(i, new Drop ((int) Math.random()*width, -10, 10));
           else if (i>4 && i<=8)
           drops.add(i, new ColorDrop ((int) Math.random()*width, -10, 10, Color.BLUE)); //drops.get(i).randomPainter()
           else
           drops.add(i, new SpeedDrop ((int) Math.random()*width, -10, 10, (int) Math.random()*10));
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

        // Fill background 
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        testDrop.draw(g);
        colorDrop.draw(g);
        fastDrop.draw(g);
        wavyDrop.draw(g);
      for(int i = 0; i<=12; i++)
       drops.get(i).draw(g);
    }

    public void update(){

        testDrop.move(width, height);
        colorDrop.move(width, height);
        fastDrop.move(width, height);
        wavyDrop.move(width, height);
        for(int i = 0; i<=12; i++)
        drops.get(i).move(width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyGooDrop tester = new MyGooDrop();
        tester.go();

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast to `Drop` when adding to the list, since all items you add inherit it

Comment: it doesn't work without the cast either :\

Comment: The cast to `Drop` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Are you getting exceptions, like IndexOutBoundsExceptions? You are adding 12 elements (`for(int i = 0; i< 12; i++)`) to your ArrayList, but you're trying to draw 13 (`for(int i = 0; i<=12; i++)`). Note the significance of `i < 12` vs. `i <= 12`.

Comment: you were right about that, but now i get my out of bounds at index 5 where it tries to start adding drops of type subclass colordrop, how could i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
drops.add(new ColorDrop ((int) Math.random()*width, -10, 10, drops.get(i).randomPainter()));
```

Your trying to get an object from the same position as you are trying to add it to (i), and calling randomPainter() on this (still null object) will result in a NPE.

As mentioned in the comments, check your for loops in update and draw methods for `i <= 12`, which should be `i < 12`, or better, `i < drops.size()`. These will currently cause ArrayIndexOutOfBounds errors.

Comment: i corrected the for loops and am currently fixing my. it paints now but they do not move correctly i will update my code in the post to show that my add now include the index

Comment: Going to need a little more information. How are they not moving correctly? What are they doing? Posting your move method will also help, though if your test drops work, there doesn't seem to be a reason your loops won't work, aside from the fact that you are constructing them with different parameters.

Comment: I've been testing my code and it seems that the fillDropList function is called but the dorps are not being added? This is strange because I do not get a nullpointer, but when I put a System.out.println("i'm making drops!") test line underneath any of the adds nothing is printed..

Comment: nevermind, it was because the arraylist size was not set before the for loop ran. it works now, just doesn't produce as many dorps as it should, but i'll keep at it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let's look at a few things bit by bit.  Seeing that you're using AWT with Graphics2D, I'm going to assume you're using JPanel or something of the sort.  If this is the case, then I'm also going to assume your

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
   ...
}
```

is at some point being called by some

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   draw((Graphics2D)g);
}
```

somewhere in your Goo class.  Also, your update method, I'm assuming is being called repeatedly in a thread.  One thing that it's missing that would probably fix the GUI not being updated would be adding a `repaint()` call like so

```
public void update(){

    testDrop.move(width, height);
    colorDrop.move(width, height);
    fastDrop.move(width, height);
    wavyDrop.move(width, height);
    for(int i = 0; i<=12; i++)
        drops.get(i).move(width, height);
    //updates the GUI
    repaint();
}
```

As for your for-loops, since you're using an ArrayList instead of an Array, do not use hard-coded values for the size throughout the code, because that defeats the purpose of using a List.

```
/**
 * Adds a bunch of new drops to the drop list, a third of each type
 * @param numOfDrops - the amount of drops to add to the list
 */
public void fillDropList (int numOfDrops)
{
    int oneThird = numOfDrops/3;
    int twoThirds = 2*numOfDrops;
    for(int i = 0; i<= numOfDrops; i++)
    {
        if (i <= oneThird)
        {
            drops.add(new Drop ((int)(Math.random()*width), -10, 10));
        }
        else if (i > oneThird && i <= twoThirds)
        {
            drops.add(new ColorDrop ((int)(Math.random()*width), -10, 10, Color.BLUE));
        }
        else
        {
             drops.add(new SpeedDrop ((int)(Math.random()*width), -10, 10, (int)(Math.random()*10)));
        }
    }
}
```

and everywhere you have a for-loop iterating through drops, use

```
for (int i = 0; i < drops.size(); i++)
```

Only other things I can recommend is consider the Strategy Pattern for your different Drop types, and watch your parenthesis.